# HTML: CSS: dynamic displayed DIV affects other DIVs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flexbox

I have a little template which can explain my question in general.

```js
$('#someBtn').on('click', function(){
 $('.notification-panel').toggle();
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.notification-panel {
  background: green;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
}

.content {
  background: yellow;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.footer {
  background: blue;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class='notification-panel'>
    Some notification
  </div>
  <div class='content'>
    Scaling to screen using vh and vw <br>
    Line 2 <br>
    Line 3 <br>
    Line 4 <br>
    Line 5 <br>
    Line 6 <br>
    Line 7 <br>
    Line 8 <br>
    Line 9 <br>
    Line 10 <br>
    Line 11 <br>
    Line 12 <br>
    Line 13 <br>
    Line 14 <br>
    Line 15 <br>
    Line 16 <br>
    Line 17 <br>
    Line 18 <br>
    Line 19 <br>
    Line 20 <br>
    Line 21 <br>
    Line 22 <br>
    Line 23 <br>
    Line 24 <br>
    <button id ="someBtn">
      Click me
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class='footer'>
    Footer
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, i have dynamic 'notification-panel' element which affects bottom elements (after toogling it shifts bottom elements down). My goal is shrinking of scrollable 'content' element's height without any shifts. I suppose flex (flex-shrink/flex-grow) should solve the problem, but i don't know how can i apply it to my template.

UPD1: 'position: fixed' for 'notification-panel' element doesn't solve the problem. It just overlaps the top part of my 'content' element, but my goal is shrinking of the 'content' element's height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flex would do this - just make your wrapper flex and remove the height from your content div and give it flex-grow (not shrink)

```js
$('#someBtn').on('click', function() {
  $('.notification-panel').toggle();
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper { /* this is optional - you can apply this directly to the body */
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  height: 100%;
}

.notification-panel {
  background: green;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
}

.content {
  flex-grow:1;               /* this makes the content panel fill the remaining space */
  background: yellow;
  overflow: auto;
}

.footer {
  background: blue;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class='notification-panel'>
    Some notification
  </div>
  <div class='content'>
    Scaling to screen using vh and vw <br> Line 2 <br> Line 3 <br> Line 4 <br> Line 5 <br> Line 6 <br> Line 7 <br> Line 8 <br> Line 9 <br> Line 10 <br> Line 11 <br> Line 12 <br> Line 13 <br> Line 14 <br> Line 15 <br> Line 16 <br> Line 17 <br> Line 18
    <br> Line 19 <br> Line 20 <br> Line 21 <br> Line 22 <br> Line 23 <br> Line 24 <br>
    <button id="someBtn">
      Click me
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class='footer'>
    Footer
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works well with my template! But i have another question. What if we change a bit my template and took placed my 'content' and 'footer' elements in some parent div? Then 'wrapper' has two children: 'notification-panel' and some parent div (which has its own children: 'content' and 'footer').  Do you have any suggestions, how can we do it with nested elements? I suppose, it is a topic for another question, but i need your opinion.

Comment: It should be doable, if you post a new question with the html structure and let me know, I'll have a look

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without flex. If you define the notification panel as `fixed` and with a `top: 0` you will have what you want. Here is a working example:

```js
$('#someBtn').on('click', function(){
  $('.notification-panel').toggle();
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.notification-panel {
  background: green;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
  // Here is the addition
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}

.content {
  background: yellow;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.footer {
  background: blue;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class='notification-panel'>
    Some notification
  </div>
  <div class='content'>
    Scaling to screen using vh and vw <br>
    Line 2 <br>
    Line 3 <br>
    Line 4 <br>
    Line 5 <br>
    Line 6 <br>
    Line 7 <br>
    Line 8 <br>
    Line 9 <br>
    Line 10 <br>
    Line 11 <br>
    Line 12 <br>
    Line 13 <br>
    Line 14 <br>
    Line 15 <br>
    Line 16 <br>
    Line 17 <br>
    Line 18 <br>
    Line 19 <br>
    Line 20 <br>
    Line 21 <br>
    Line 22 <br>
    Line 23 <br>
    Line 24 <br>
    <button id ="someBtn">
      Click me
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class='footer'>
    Footer
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below CSS property to notification panel
Also move the panel inside content.

```
position: -webkit-sticky;
position: sticky;
top: 0;
```

Check this  example

```js
$('#someBtn').on('click', function(){
 $('.notification-panel').toggle();
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.notification-panel {
  background: green;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.content {
  background: yellow;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.footer {
  background: blue;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class='content'>
    <div class='notification-panel'>
        Some notification
    </div>
    Scaling to screen using vh and vw <br>
    Line 2 <br>
    Line 3 <br>
    Line 4 <br>
    Line 5 <br>
    Line 6 <br>
    Line 7 <br>
    Line 8 <br>
    Line 9 <br>
    Line 10 <br>
    Line 11 <br>
    Line 12 <br>
    Line 13 <br>
    Line 14 <br>
    Line 15 <br>
    Line 16 <br>
    Line 17 <br>
    Line 18 <br>
    Line 19 <br>
    Line 20 <br>
    Line 21 <br>
    Line 22 <br>
    Line 23 <br>
    Line 24 <br>
    <button id ="someBtn">
      Click me
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class='footer'>
    Footer
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Maybe you are needed this code here**

Description: when you click the button then the `notification-panel` set style display block by the jquery toggle function. a block element normally not entered on his won area other elements. So, you can talk the `notification-panel` `position : { absolute}` a position absolute element don't effect inner other element height. I am also add a simple animation `toggle` to `slideToggle(300)` slide and toggle with 300-millisecond animation. maybe it's fixed your problem.

```js
$('#someBtn').on('click', function(){
 $('.notification-panel').slideToggle(300);
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.notification-panel {
  background: green;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
  position:fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.content {
  background: yellow;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.footer {
  background: blue;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class='notification-panel'>
    Some notification
  </div>
  <div class='content'>
    Scaling to screen using vh and vw <br>
    Line 2 <br>
    Line 3 <br>
    Line 4 <br>
    Line 5 <br>
    Line 6 <br>
    Line 7 <br>
    Line 8 <br>
    Line 9 <br>
    Line 10 <br>
    Line 11 <br>
    Line 12 <br>
    Line 13 <br>
    Line 14 <br>
    Line 15 <br>
    Line 16 <br>
    Line 17 <br>
    Line 18 <br>
    Line 19 <br>
    Line 20 <br>
    Line 21 <br>
    Line 22 <br>
    Line 23 <br>
    Line 24 <br>
    <button id ="someBtn">
      Click me
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class='footer'>
    Footer
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Problem with this is that it overlaps the first line.

Comment: you can also add more space when clicking the button

Comment: That is not the proper solution. How much space should be added? It depends on the font-size. Not scalable at all.

Comment: you get 'notification-panel' height and then keeps the content top padding that's enough simple code here the link: http://api.jquery.com/height/

Comment: That's is a hack.

Answer (score 0):

Use `position: absolute` for don't make height changes. See bellow:

```js
var isShowing = false;
$('#someBtn').on('click', function(){
 if ( !isShowing ) {
     isShowing = true;
     $('.notification-panel').addClass('show') 
  }
  else {
    $('.notification-panel').removeClass('show')
    isShowing = false;
  }
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position:relative;
}

.notification-panel {
  background: green;
  width: 100%;
  
  position: absolute; /* make floating, so don't change height */
  opacity: 0.0; /* hide on load */
  pointer-events: none;
  transform: translateY( -20px );
  transition: opacity 300ms, transform 300ms; /* animate */
}

.show { /* becomes visible  */
  opacity: 1.0;
  transform: translate(0);
}

.content {
  background: yellow;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.footer {
  background: blue;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class='notification-panel'>
    Some notification
  </div>
  <div class='content'>
    Scaling to screen using vh and vw <br>
    Line 2 <br>
    Line 3 <br>
    Line 4 <br>
    Line 5 <br>
    Line 6 <br>
    Line 7 <br>
    Line 8 <br>
    Line 9 <br>
    Line 10 <br>
    Line 11 <br>
    Line 12 <br>
    Line 13 <br>
    Line 14 <br>
    Line 15 <br>
    Line 16 <br>
    Line 17 <br>
    Line 18 <br>
    Line 19 <br>
    Line 20 <br>
    Line 21 <br>
    Line 22 <br>
    Line 23 <br>
    Line 24 <br>
    <button id ="someBtn">
      Click me
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class='footer'>
    Footer
  </div>
</div>
```